# Odoo 8 , how to convert an existing Quotation to Sales order via XMLRPC

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, xml-rpc

**1]** I have already created a Quotation  in Odoo 8 Setup via XMLRPC :

```
return_id = api.execute_kw(db, uid, pwd, 'sale.order','create',[{'note':'******~~~~~********','state':'draft','order_policy':'manual','amount_tax':0.0,'amount_untaxed':0.0,'amount_total':0.0,'partner_invoice_id':22, 'partner_shipping_id':22}])
```

**2]** AND then added an order line too to this quotation :

```
return_id =  api.execute_kw(db, uid, pwd,'sale.order.line','create',  [{ 'product_id':2,'product_uos_quantity':1.000,   'order_id':37, 'quantity':1 }]);
```

Now ***what I need*** is to further convert this quotation to sales order ***via XMLRPC***   so that it stimulates all the normal 'confirm sale' button actions like logging message, converting quotation to sales order and making all necessary changes in all the required tables.

Answer (score 3):

You will confirm sale order by xmlrpc using below code. Here sale_order_id is the id of the sale order, that you get when creating the sale order. By executing code, the Quotation convert into sale order.

```
api.exec_workflow(db, uid, password, 'sale.order', 'order_confirm', sale_order_id)
```